# Ввод. Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, test-automation

Нужно сымитировать нажатие клавиши. Не ввод по средствам `SendKeys`, а именно открыть страницу и сымитировать нажатие кнопки на клавиатуре.

Есть примерно такой тест:

```
    webDriver.get("http://pdd.by/tasks/online/");
    webSite.taskPage().startClick();
    // И тут нужна имитация нажатия
```

Можно ли вообще это реализовать при помощи Selenium. Если да - то как?

Пробовал `robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_3);`для имитации нажатия 3. Но увы и ах...

Comment: А почему `SendKeys` не подходит? в чем проблема собственно?

Answer (score 2):

В `Selenium Webdriver` для обработки событий мыши и клавиатуры используется `Advanced User Interactions API`. В нем есть `Actions`, которые и нужны нам для генерации определенной последовательности действий.

Пример, как пользоваться ими:

1. Импортируем `Actions` и `Action` классы:

   ```
   import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Action;
   import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
   ```
2. Создаем объект класса `Actions`, с помощью которого будем генерировать действия:

   ```
   Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
   ```
3. Инициализируем объект класса `Action` с помощью `builder`:

   ```
   Action keyXPressed = builder.sendKeys("x").build();
   ```
4. Теперь в любом месте тестирующего кода мы можем исполнить эту последовательность действий следующим образом:

   ```
   keyXPressed.perform();
   ```

Что же касается `Java Robot`, то он не совсем подходит для данной задачи. Почему? Подробно ответ на этот вопрос дан [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28005007/selenium-actions-or-java-awt-robot).

Так что Вам нужно пользоваться классами `Action` и `Actions`.

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо за столь развернутый ответ, но. . .
Не знаю почему, но после объявления  `Actions builder = new Actions(webDriver);` тесты перестали запускаться по причине **java.lang.NullPointerException** , ссылаясь именно на эту строку.

Comment: @PavelBobrov не запускалось потому, что в конструктор передавался `webDriver`, который был нулевым указателем. Рад, что смог помочь Вам.

Answer (score 1):

```
webDriver.findElement(By.linkText(text)).click();
```

У кнопки же есть какой-то текст

Comment: И как же мне заставить webdriver искать linktext на физической клавиатуре?

Comment: Про клавиатуру не заметил) ниже ответили уже